# Tumblr creates paragraph that i don't want

Tags: jquery, tumblr, paragraph

Im using a combination of Jquery scripts with Divs inside my text. Tumblr automatically puts paragraphs around isolated text, and thereby creates a space behind my links. This happens even if i manually remove them in html mode.

How could one solve this?
Very grateful for any answer.

**I would like it to look like this:**
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy *text*, of the printing and typesetting industry.
*Link 1*, *Link 2*

**But it ends up looking like this:**
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy *text* , of the printing and typesetting industry. *Link 1* , *Link 2*

See example: http://roingbaer.com

HTML after tumblr messes it up:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
<div class="hover"><a href="http://example.com">text</a>
<div class="front"><img src="http://images.roingbaer.com/ludvig.png" /></div>
</div>
<p>, of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<div class="hover">Link 1
<div class="front"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lyz7fjMdnN1rp3eymo1_r2_500.jpg" /></div>
<div class="back"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lyz7fjMdnN1rp3eymo1_r2_500.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<p>,</p>
<div class="hover">Link 2
<div class="front"><iframe frameborder="0" height="233" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VMeXGE_a8Gg" width="400"></iframe></div>
<div class="back"><iframe frameborder="0" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VMeXGE_a8Gg" width="853"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".front").each(function() {
 var right = Math.floor(Math.random()*800);
 var top = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);

 $(this).css({'margin-right': right});
 $(this).css({'margin-top': top});
});

hoverdiv = $("div.hover")

hoverdiv.on("hover", function() {
$(this).children(".front").show()
});
hoverdiv.on("mouseleave", function() {
$(this).children(".front").hide()
})
hoverdiv.on("click", function() {
$(this).children(".back").toggle()
$(this).children(".front").hide()
});
```

CSS

```
.back { 
display:none;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
text-align:right;
}

.front
{ 
display:none;
max-height:200px;
max-width:auto;
position:fixed;
z-index:-50;
top:0;
right:100px;
}

.hover { 
cursor:pointer;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-style:italic;
display:inline;
}
```

Relevant Tumblr code:

```
<div id="content">
<!-- Loops for each post-type -->
{block:Posts}
  <div class="post {TagsAsClasses}">
    <div class="post-header">
{block:Text}
      <p class="post-metadata">
      </p>
    </div> <!-- end post-header -->

              <div class="text">
                        <h3>{Title}</h3>

      {Body}
    </div>
    {/block:Text}
```

Comment: Can you post your Tumblr source code? The bit with {post} and such?

Comment: You might be better off using `span` elements for your inline needs than coercing (by default block level) `div` elements to inline display. Seems Tumblr’s HTML generator tries to sort out block level elements by adding paragraph markup…

Comment: @Artroing did you find a solution?